# How do I build a query using MQL to fetch data from Log based metric?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have a log based metric where the resource type is not defined.  How do I build a MQL query for a log based metric for the following:

`logging.googleapis.com/user/MY_METRIC`

If I use the "configuration view" in Metric Explorer the data shows. However when I switch to MQL I can't seem to create the correct filter.

`fetch logging.googleapis.com/user/MY_METRIC` gives me syntax errors for resource type not defined.

Comment: I have tested in my environment and checked it is mandatory to give the resource type in MQL. Can you have a try by giving the resource in MQL query and have a checkl.

Comment: Have u tried the above  solution. Is your issue resolved?

Comment: Yeah your suggestion worked. Thank you. If the logs come from a VM then the resource type must be selected as compute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the logs come from a VM then the resource type must be selected as compute.

Resource type must be declared.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested in my environment and checked it is mandatory to give the resource type in MQL. This will work.